# Debezium Postgres Connector "After applying the include/exclude list filters, no changes will be captured"

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, debezium, debezium-engine, debezium-server

I am using Debezium (a Kafka Connector) to capture Postgres database changes and I am getting an error from Debezium.  Does anyone know what the error below means and perhaps offer a suggestion to fix it.

A bit more debugging info:

- I tried both "schema.include.list": "banking" and "database.include.list": "banking"... neither works
- I tried debezium/connect:1.4 and it works... but not with debezium/connect:1.5+ (1.9 is as high a version as is available and it does not work (same error as below)

```
Postgres|dbserver1|snapshot  After applying the include/exclude list filters, no changes will be captured. Please check your configuration!   [io.debezium.relational.RelationalDatabaseSchema]
```

I have verified (in the logs) that Kafka (and schema registry etc) is running properly, and the Debezium connector seems to have started, and Postgres iw working properly and the database and tables are created.

Below is the Debezium connector configuration:

```
{
    "name": "banking-postgres-connector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
        "database.hostname": "postgres",
        "database.port": "5432",
        "database.user": "postgres",
        "database.password": "postgres",
        "database.dbname" : "banking",
        "database.server.name": "dbserver1",
        "database.include.list": "banking",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "table.include.list": "public.x_account,public.x_party,public.x_product,public.x_transaction"
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you want `schema.include.list`? Otherwise, I don't think you need `public.` prefix on the tables

Comment: @OneCricketeer - thanks for the advice - I tried this and unfortunately it does not work... I updated the question to reflect this, plus after more debugging, it seems that it *works* with debezium/connect:1.4 but *does not work* with any higher version unto debezium/connect:1.9 (latest version)... best I can figure is there is difference between the kafka, connect, or postgres docker-compose files... will post more details (or answers) as I progress

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After many hours debugging (plus some advice from @OneCricketeer which pointed me in the right direction), I managed to get a configuration that works with debezium/connect:1.9.  The solution was to use defaults by eliminating configuration items:

```
database.include.list
schema.include.list
```

This final working Debezium configuration is as follows:

```
{
    "name": "banking-postgres-connector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
        "database.hostname": "postgres",
        "database.port": "5432",
        "database.user": "postgres",
        "database.password": "postgres",
        "database.dbname" : "banking",
        "database.server.name": "dbserver1",
        "tasks.max": "1"
    }
}
```

This does point to a minor gap in the Debezium documentation and code:

1. The documentation should provide valid values (examples) for either "schema.include.list" or "database.include.list" since adding the database name alone for either value does not seem to work for postgres...
2. It would be great to get more information from the logs... the warning message was both hard to find/understand and left one with little recourse. Since this is a situation where *no* data is captured, it may warrant a higher importance (log an error?)

NOTE: I offer the above as humble suggestions because I find Debezium to be an OUTSTANDING product!

Comment: This should pull all the banking db tables, but it seems you only wanted a handful?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yes, this gets them all (I use table.include.list properties that allow me to filter them) - the key issue which was weird is that when I specified "banking" in the database.include.list or schema.include.list it did not find any at all, which this fixes)

Comment: @EricBroda, that is the correct behavior. As the config means only include "banking" database, and in the table.include.list above only allows tables from public database.

`
 "database.dbname" : "banking",
 "table.include.list":"public.x_account, public.x_party"
`

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue myself. Structure of the database server when viewed in pgadmin is

```
  Servers
   Server Name (Local)
    Databases (9)
     database_1
      ...
      Schemas(1)
        public 
          ...
          Tables (56)
             table_1
             ...
```

Have configs values set

```
debezium.source.database.dbname = database_1
debezium.source.schema.include.list=public
```

Then tried the below seperately with

```
debezium.source.table.include.list=table_1
debezium.source.table.include.list=public.table_1
```

But with no success, same warning log.

Comment: have you tried an actual list: [""] ... ?